# Succinctly Adding Custom Event Triggers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a rather large and convoluted JavaScript module that is used on multiple pages of my site. After a bit of searching and fiddling, I came up with the following structure to run some extra code when one of the module's functions run on a specific page.

```
// within module definition that is used across multiple pages
function some_module_method(){
  $.event.trigger( 'custom_event' );
}

// bit of functionality that I'm trying to add to a single page
$( '#some-element' ).on( 'custom_event', function(){
  console.log( 'The custom event has just been triggered!' );
} );
```

One problem I'm having is that when I'm expecting this event to only trigger once, it will go off 2-4 times in quick succession. Is this a problem with the structure above that I'm using to trigger and attach this event, or probably something else?

Also, how can I attach a function to an event without referencing some DOM object? Simply using `$.on()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, it's a little hard to say without seeing an example. And I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure $.trigger() will not work like you're using it.  It has to be attached to a jQuery object e.g.. `$().trigger()`.

And for your second question... You don't have to use a DOM element exactly, but you can use an empty jquery object like `$({}).on()`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ek6n/).

Hope this helps some.

On a side note, you may be confusing jQuery object methods with core methods. [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/legacy#chapter-4) is a little info just in case.

Comment: Sorry, code I was running was $.event.trigger( 'custom_event' ). I've corrected my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah okay. In that case I think you may be using $.Event wrong.  Check out the examples [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#some-element').trigger('custom_event');
```

instead of

```
$.trigger('custom_event');
```